# Problem with function/ replacement has length zero

Tags: r, categorical-data, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I'm trying to run the following function proposed by Lai et al., 2021, that aims to compare fit differences in non-nested models with categorical AVs. The Models look like this:

```
Mod1  <- '
                 # Measurement models
# Predictor Variables
                 A   =~ NoEPA2 + ChEPA2 + SvEPA2                          
                 N   =~ NoEPN2 + ChEPN2 + SvEPN2                          
  # Outcome Variables
                 I   =~ DE_VORH + AN_VORH + AINTMAX                                                     
                 EX  =~ C_VORH  + O_VORH + AD_MAX                     
# Control variables         
                 AGE   =~ age
                 age ~~ 0*age
                 SEX   =~ sex
                 sex   ~~ 0*sex
                 EDU =~ edu
                 edu ~~ 0* edu
                 
#Error correlation A, N, E
                 NoEPA1 ~~ NoEPN1 
                 ChEPA1 ~~ ChEPN1 
                 SvEPA1 ~~ SvEPN1 
# Correlations DV         
                 A ~~ N  
                 I ~~ EX
                 
  # Paths
                 I ~ A + N + AGE + SEX + EDU 
                 EX ~ A + N + AGE + SEX + EDU 
'
Sem2 <- sem(Mod1, 
             data=a,
             estimator     = "WLSMV",
             conditional.x = FALSE,
             mimic         = "Mplus",
             ordered       = c("DE_VORH", "AN_VORH","AINTMAX","O_VORH",  "C_VORH","AD_MAX"))

summary(sem2, 
        fit.measures = TRUE,  
        standardize  = TRUE, 
        rsquare      = TRUE, 
        estimates    = TRUE, 
        ci           = FALSE)


Mod2  <- '
                 # Measurement models
# Predictor Variables
                 A   =~ NoEPA1 + ChEPA1 + SvEPA1                          
                 N   =~ NoEPN1 + ChEPN1 + SvEPN1                          
                 E    =~ MxStEPEM + ChEPEM1  + SvEPEM1
                 
# Outcome Variables
                 I   =~ DE_VORH + AN_VORH + AINTMAX                                                     
                 EX   =~ C_VORH  + O_VORH + AD_MAX                     
# Control variables         
                 AGE   =~ age
                 age ~~ 0*age
                 SEX   =~ sex
                 sex   ~~ 0*sex
                 EDU =~ edu
                 edu ~~ 0* edu
                 
#Error correlation A, N, E
                 NoEPA1 ~~ NoEPN1 + MxStEPEM
                 NoEPN1 ~~ MxStEPEM
                 ChEPA1 ~~ ChEPN1 + ChEPEM1
                 ChEPN1 ~~ ChEPEM1
                 SvEPA1 ~~ SvEPN1 + SvEPEM1
                 SvEPN1 ~~ SvEPEM1
# Correlations DV         
                 A ~~ N + E 
                 N ~~ E  
                 I ~~ EX
                 
  # Paths
                 I ~ A + N + E + AGE + SEX + EDU 
                 EX ~ A + N + E + AGE + SEX + EDU 
'
sem3a <- sem(Mod2, 
             data=a,
             estimator     = "WLSMV",
             conditional.x = FALSE,
             mimic         = "Mplus",
             ordered       = c("DE_VORH", "AN_VORH", "AINTMAX", "O_VORH","C_VORH","AD_MAX"))

summary(sem3a, 
        fit.measures = TRUE,  
        standardize  = TRUE, 
        rsquare      = TRUE, 
        estimates    = TRUE, 
        ci           = FALSE)
```

The function I want to apply looks like this:

```
## The function below returns point estimate and standard error for
## ∆RMSEA, ∆CFI, and ∆SRMR between two competing models A & B given categorical data.
## The two models do not need to be nested.

# fitA = Fitted 'lavaan' model object for Model A
# fitB = Fitted 'lavaan' model object for Model B
# fitZ = Fitted 'lavaan' model object for the baseline model for CFI


fit.diff.cat <- function(fitA, fitB){
    ###################################### 
    # Internal functions 
    ######################################

    # Rearrange the model-implied correlation matrix of 'fitB' so that its columns and rows
    # are in the same order as that in the model-implied correlation matrix of 'fitA' 
    rearrange.P.theta <- function(fitA, fitB){
      R <- inspect(fitA, "sampstat")$'cov'
      p <- dim(R)[1]
      R <- as.matrix(R, p, p)
      P.theta.A <- inspect(fitA, "cov.ov")
      P.theta.B0 <- inspect(fitB, "cov.ov")
      target.var.names <- rownames(R)
      current.var.names <- rownames(P.theta.B0)
      P.theta.B <- matrix(NA, p, p)
      rownames(P.theta.B) <- colnames(P.theta.B) <- target.var.names
      
        for (i.row in 1:p){
          for(i.col in 1:p){
            row.name <- target.var.names[i.row]
            col.name <- target.var.names[i.col]
            pick.row <- which(current.var.names==row.name)
            pick.col <- which(current.var.names==col.name)  
            P.theta.B[i.row, i.col] <- P.theta.B0[pick.row, pick.col]
          }
        }
      return(P.theta.B) 
    }# End of rearrange.P.theta()


    # Rearrange the model-implied thresholds of 'fitB' so that its names
    # are in the same order as that in the model-implied thresholds 'fitA' 
    rearrange.thresh <- function(fitA, fitB){
      thresh <- inspect(fitA, "sampstat")$th
      thresh.B0 <- inspect(fitB, "th")
      target.var.names <- names(thresh)
      current.var.names <- names(thresh.B0)
      n.thresh <- length(thresh)
      thresh.B <- rep(NA, n.thresh)
      names(thresh.B) <- target.var.names
      
        for (i in 1:n.thresh){
            name <- target.var.names[i]
            pick.name <- which(current.var.names==name)
            thresh.B[i] <- thresh.B0[pick.name]
        }
      return(thresh.B)  
    }# End of rearrange.thresh()


    # Rearrange the Delta matrix of 'fitB' so that its rows are
    # in the same order as that in the Delta matrix of 'fitA'. 
    # Delta = derivative of P(theta) wrt theta
    rearrange.Delta <- function(fitA, fitB){
      Delta.B0 <- lavaan:::computeDelta(fitB@Model)[[1]]
      n.theta <- dim(Delta.B0)[2] 
      
      thresh <- inspect(fitA, "sampstat")$th
      thresh.B0 <- inspect(fitB, "th")
      target.var.names <- names(thresh)
      current.var.names <- names(thresh.B0)
      n.thresh <- length(thresh)
      Delta.th <- matrix(NA, n.thresh, n.theta)
      rownames(Delta.th) <- target.var.names 

      for (i in 1:n.thresh){
        name <- target.var.names[i]
        pick.name <- which(current.var.names==name)
        Delta.th[i,] <- Delta.B0[pick.name,]
        }
        
      P.theta.B0 <- inspect(fitB, "cov.ov")  
      R <- inspect(fitA, "sampstat")$'cov'
      p <- dim(R)[1]
      target.var.names <- rownames(R)
      current.var.names <- rownames(P.theta.B0)
      n.rho <- p*(p-1)/2
      current.matrix <- matrix(NA, p, p)
      current.matrix[lower.tri(current.matrix, diag=FALSE)] <- 1:n.rho
      pick.vech <- rep(NA, n.rho)
      j <- 1
      
      for(i.col in 1:(p-1)){
        for(i.row in (i.col+1):p){
          row.name <- target.var.names[i.row]
          col.name <- target.var.names[i.col]
          pick.row <- which(current.var.names==row.name) 
          pick.col <- which(current.var.names==col.name)
          if(pick.row >= pick.col) pick.vech[j] <- current.matrix[pick.row, pick.col]
          if(pick.row < pick.col) pick.vech[j] <- current.matrix[pick.col, pick.row]
          j <- j+1
        }
      } 

      Delta.rho <- matrix(NA, n.rho, n.theta)
      for(i in 1:n.rho){
        pick <- pick.vech[i] + n.thresh
        Delta.rho[i,] <- Delta.B0[pick,]  
      }

      Delta.B <- rbind(Delta.th, Delta.rho) 
      return(Delta.B)
    }# End of rearrange.Delta()


###################################### 
# Main function 
######################################
  H.A <- inspect(fitA, "hessian")*2
  H.B <- inspect(fitB, "hessian")*2
  H.A.inv <- try(chol2inv(chol(H.A)), TRUE)
  H.B.inv <- try(chol2inv(chol(H.B)), TRUE)
  
  if(class(H.A.inv)=="matrix" & class(H.B.inv)=="matrix"){
    n <- inspect(fitA, "nobs")
    dA <- as.numeric(fitmeasures(fitA, "df"))
    dB <- as.numeric(fitmeasures(fitB, "df"))

    P.B <- rearrange.P.theta(fitA, fitB)
    p <- dim(P.B)[1]
    rho.B <- lav_matrix_vech(P.B, diagonal = FALSE)
    thresh.B <- rearrange.thresh(fitA, fitB)
    estB <- c(thresh.B, rho.B)
    
    m <- inspect(fitA, "wls.obs")
    estA <- inspect(fitA, "wls.est")
    eA <- m - estA
    eB <- m - estB
    Gamma <- inspect(fitA, "gamma")
    DeltaA <- lavaan:::computeDelta(fitA@Model)[[1]]
    DeltaB <- rearrange.Delta(fitA, fitB)
    p1 <- dim(DeltaA)[1]
    
    g.A <- 2*t(eA)
    K.A <- (-2)*t(DeltaA)
    T.A <- 2*diag(1, p1)
    Q.A <- T.A - t(K.A)%*%H.A.inv%*%K.A 
    G.A <- t(eA) %*% eA
    G.A.bc0 <- G.A - sum(diag(Q.A%*%Gamma))/(2*n)
    G.A.bc <- ifelse(G.A.bc0 < 0, 0, G.A.bc0)
 
    g.B <- 2*t(eB)
    K.B <- (-2)*t(DeltaB)
    T.B <- 2*diag(1, p1)
    Q.B <- T.B - t(K.B)%*%H.B.inv%*%K.B 
    G.B <- t(eB) %*% eB
    G.B.bc0 <- G.B - sum(diag(Q.B%*%Gamma))/(2*n) 
    G.B.bc <- ifelse(G.B.bc0 < 0, 0, G.B.bc0)
 
    R <- inspect(fitA, "sampstat")$cov
    r <- lav_matrix_vech(R, diagonal = FALSE)
    k <- length(r)
    G.Z <- t(r) %*% r
    G.Z.bc0 <- G.Z - sum(diag(Gamma))/n
    G.Z.bc <- ifelse(G.Z.bc0 < 0, 0, G.Z.bc0)
 
    G.A1 <- ifelse(G.A.bc > 0, G.A.bc, G.A)
    G.B1 <- ifelse(G.B.bc > 0, G.B.bc, G.B)
    G.Z1 <- ifelse(G.Z.bc > 0, G.Z.bc, G.Z)
    
    ## RMSEA diff
    rmsea.AB <- sqrt(G.A.bc/dA) - sqrt(G.B.bc/dB)
        
    J.rmsea.1 <- cbind( 1/(2*sqrt(dA*G.A1)), -1/(2*sqrt(dB*G.B1)) )
    J.rmsea.2 <- rbind(g.A, g.B)
    J.rmsea <- J.rmsea.1 %*% J.rmsea.2
    var.rmsea.AB <- J.rmsea %*% Gamma %*% t(J.rmsea) / n
    se.rmsea.AB <- sqrt(var.rmsea.AB)

    ## CFI diff
    cfi.AB <- (G.B.bc - G.A.bc) / G.Z.bc
    
    n.thresh <- length(fitted(fitA)$th)
    r1 <- c(rep(0, n.thresh), r)
    J.cfi.1 <- cbind( -1/G.Z1, 1/G.Z1, (G.A1-G.B1)/G.Z1^2 )
    J.cfi.2 <- rbind(g.A, g.B, 2*t(r1) )
    J.cfi <- J.cfi.1 %*% J.cfi.2
    var.cfi.AB <- J.cfi %*% Gamma %*% t(J.cfi) / n
    se.cfi.AB <- sqrt(var.cfi.AB)

    ## SRMR diff
    srmr.AB <- sqrt(G.A.bc/k) - sqrt(G.B.bc/k)
    
    J.srmr.1 <- cbind( 1/(2*sqrt(k*G.A1)), -1/(2*sqrt(k*G.B1)) )
    J.srmr.2 <- rbind(g.A, g.B)
    J.srmr <- J.srmr.1 %*% J.srmr.2
    var.srmr.AB <- J.srmr %*% Gamma %*% t(J.srmr) / n
    se.srmr.AB <- sqrt(var.srmr.AB) 
    
    #######
    output <- c(rmsea.AB, se.rmsea.AB,
                cfi.AB, se.cfi.AB,
                srmr.AB, se.srmr.AB)
    names(output) <- c("rmsea.AB", "se.rmsea.AB", 
                    "cfi.AB", "se.cfi.AB",
                    "srmr.AB", "se.srmr.AB")  
    }# End of if Hessian is positive definite
    else{output <- rep(NA, 6)}
 
  return(output)
}
```

When I enter my fitted models, the following error is returned:

> Error in P.theta.B[i.row, i.col] <- P.theta.B0[pick.row, pick.col] :
> replacement has length zero<

Now I tried to run the commands step by step and it seems that this error is produced at the beginning of the internal functions running this step:

```
P.theta.B[i.row, i.col] <- P.theta.B0[pick.row, pick.col]
```

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot there? I'm left with a lot of questionmarks.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error (I have no data), but when you debug and step to that line, have you looked at `pick.row` and `pick.col` to see that they are not empty and have something meaningful? If "yes" to both, check `i.row` and `i.col` as well. If any of those are empty or `NA`, then backtrace the previous lines to see which line causes the problem, and keep back-tracing that way.

Comment: The citation is behind a paywall asking for $45. Why not send this question to the authors? They are the ones who decided where to submit their article.

Comment: @r2evans I edited the question including the models I am using. Maybe that helps. Also...I did try to execute the function step by step. Within the for i in -loop it seems as if the i.col produces something weird (result = integer(0) instead of a number). But maybe, that has something to do with not running the whole function altogether?

Comment: What is the output when you run `inspect(fitA, "sampstat")$'cov'` with fitA being the model which you later give to the function as fitA

Comment: The command return the covariance matrix of the first SEM and seems to work fine. However, a colleague recommended running the for-i-loop by hand, step by step, which I did. The problem seems to be rooted in different var-names. for i.row=7 and i.col=1 the command ```pick.row <- which(current.var.names==row.name)``` returns integer(0) instead of a row-number, because it is looking for "NoEPA2" which does not exist in the object "current.var.names". Here the corresponding var-name is "MxStEPEM", since it is another model with other indicators. Does the function only work with same var-names?